# Set up printing with a networked LPR printer?

Tags: printing

I'm trying to set up printing to a networked LPR printer, but I can't seem to make it work. The connexion information that IT gives is:

Print Spooler: printing.domain.edu

Printer Name: PrinterName

Print port: 515

Bidirectional: Disabled

It's an HP LaserJet p4015x, and I'm using the "HP LaserJet p4015x, hpcups 3.10.6 (color, 2-sided printing)" driver, according to CUPS. I have tried installing via the CUPS admin interface as lpd://printing.domain.edu:515/PrinterName, lpd://printing.domain.edu/PrinterName, and http://printing.domain.edu:515/PrinterName, and none of these has worked (i.e. test pages show up as "stopped").

Comment: `lpd://` sounds right (515 is the default port so it should work with or without it). Try `telnet printing.domain.edu 515`, just to see if it's a firewall blocking you. If you get a connection, type `Ctrl+]` then `Ctrl+D` to exit telnet. Also, look for error messages from Cups in `/var/log/cups/error_log`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The telnet connexion worked fine, so I figured it was probably a driver error, and indeed the log was complaining that the hpcups filter didn't exist. Even after I installed the hplips and hplips-cups packages, though, neither of the two drivers (hpijs and hpcups) in the CUPS install database actually worked. However, there was a PPD file in /usr/share/ppd/HP that does work. [I also discovered, via telnet, that the 'printing' subdomain is actually an alias for 'coruscant.domain.edu', which made me happy...]

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.